# ASP.NET MVC 6 Core - Validation issue / bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I've migrated an MVC4 app to MVC6 (both .NET 4.6.1) and am hitting numerous errors with the inbuilt model validation.

I have a number of complex models that are posted to controllers, and unless I disable validation on each model under configure services, they throw unnecessary exceptions relating to properties that are irrelevant to validation, or just hang after postback without reaching the controller action.

I have added the following line to MVC Configuration for all my affected classes, but I've now got a model that requires validation, so turning it off will cause numerous code changes.

```
options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(TestModel)));
```

I tried this with a test app and can replicate the issue:

Test Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(TestModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Test Model (for example)

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int NameLength
    {
        get
        {
            return Name.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Without the validation attributes, the code works fine, but is not validated (obviously).

But when this model is posted, a NullReference exception is thrown by the NameLength property, even though no code references it, the property is read only, and the property it depends on is required. This validation happens before control is returned to the controller.

I've tried disabling this functionality in MvcOptions, but it doesn't have any effect:

```
options.MaxValidationDepth = null;
options.AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes = false;
options.AllowShortCircuitingValidationWhenNoValidatorsArePresent = true;
```

I don't know if there's a setting I'm missing, but I would expect the default functionality to ignore properties without validation attributes, or am I doing something wrong?.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Further to @Henks suggestion, I've added the ValidateNever attribute to the readonly properties of one class I was having problems with, which has worked, so the postback reaches the controller now, but its still calling the properties, it just seems to ignore the result:

```
[ValidateNever]
public Competition PrimaryCompetition
{
    get
    {
        return GetCompetition(true);
    }
}
```

This still triggers a null reference exception because it relies on another property that is [Required] but is not validated first.

I'm beginning to think this is a bug rather than an error on my part.

Comment: Have you seen `ValidateNeverAttribute` ?

Comment: Is the model coming in correctly on the controller?

Comment: @Henk, thanks for that, I looked for NoValidate or IgnoreValidation didn't see ValidateNever. It works on my test app. I'll try it on my main project, but it seems an odd decision to have to explicitly exclude properties for validation, as well as explicitly include them!.

Comment: @James. No it hangs without raising an exception, unless one of the properties on the model throws an exception of course. I'll try Henks suggestion, but its a long winded fix if it works!.

Answer (score 0):

### Why this happens

I haven't seen this issue with simple types (like in some of the example code you posted), but we just had a similar issue with complex types.

From looking at the source code, this has to do with how the complex model binder works. It steps through every **public property getter that is a complex type** (e.g. a class) when posted regardless of whether the property was used at all. I think this may be an intentional choice by Microsoft because it is possible that the underlying properties of a complex type could be settable.

For example if your `Competition` class and `PrimaryCompetition` property on another class (called `Test` here) looked like this:

```
public class Competition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roster { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

public class Test
{
    public Competition PrimaryCompetition
    {
        get
            {
                return AllCompetitions.First();
            }
    }
    
    public List<Competition> AllCompetitions { get; set; } = new List<Competition>();
    
}
```

Underlying properties of `PrimaryCompetition` can be modified even though it has no setter:

```
var competition = new Competition {
    Name = "Soccer"
};
competition.Roster.Add("Sara");

var test = new Test();

// This code outputs "Sara"
test.AllCompetitions.Add(competition);
Console.WriteLine(test.PrimaryCompetition.Roster[0]);

// This code outputs "Amanda"
test.PrimaryCompetition.Roster[0] = "Amanda";
Console.WriteLine(test.PrimaryCompetition.Roster[0]);
```

### Possible solutions

1. Make the property a method instead:

```
public Competition PrimaryCompetition() => GetCompetition(true);
```

2. Make the property `internal` instead of `public`:

```
internal Competition PrimaryCompetition
{
    get
    {
        return GetCompetition(true);
    }
}
```

3. Add the `ValidateNever` and `BindNever` attributes to the property:

```
[BindNever]
[ValidateNever]
public Competition PrimaryCompetition
{
    get
    {
        return GetCompetition(true);
    }
}
```

We decided to go with option 1 since in Microsoft's best practices they recommend not throwing exceptions from getters [Property Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property).

> Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method.